# Is there a way to test that a function passed with mapDispatchToProps was called using RTL when there is no relevant change in UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

Is there a way to test that a function passed with `mapDispatchToProps` was called using RTL when there is no relevant change in UI?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/325#issuecomment-199449298), you don't need to test that `mapDispatchToPros` *works* (this is redux's responsibility).
What you *should* probably do is exporting the non-connected component, and passing the jest functions in props directly.

For example :

```
export const Component = ({ someFn }) => {
  ...
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  someFn: ...
};

export connect(...)(Component)
```

```js
import { Component } from './component.js';

...

it('calls someFn on submit', () => {
  const someFn = jest.fn()
  const component = mounted(<Component someFn={someFn} />)
  component.simulate('submit')
  expect(someFn).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Hope this helps